# Boot hangs at Stopping userspace bootsplash

Tags: boot, grub2, amd-graphics

I have an ubuntu server that keeps hanging at boot time.

It hangs at a message that says "Stopping userspace bootsplash".

I have different kernel versions in grub but all of them hang in the same place. I also have tried booting in recovery mode and the same thing happens.

I have tried adding "nomodeset" and "radeon.modeset=1" to the grub line to try and see if I was able to boot, but no luck there.

I have tried hitting Ctrl+Alt+F1 when the process is stuck, but I get no console, or better, I get a black screen but not the "login:" prompt.

I have also seen a "no ums support in radeon module", not sure if it shows when I hit escape when seeing the boot splash screen, or when I change with Ctrl+Alt+F1.

This is a ubuntu based distro, not ubuntu itself. It's called Zentyal, and was not installed or configured by me.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Zentanyl is not Ubuntu, nor an official flavor, thus is *off-topic* on this web site. I'd suggest asking on Stack Exchange's Unix & Linux website.

Comment: @guiverc I understand it is not ubuntu, I just felt it belonged here since it is ubuntu based. I will try on that site, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed a similar issue on my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop environment.

My issue was most likely a buggy amdgpu firmware in the latest linux-firmware package.

See my solution/workaround [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330465/ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-frequently-hangs-on-reboot-after-install-and-removal-of-liquo).

You can verify if the linux-firmware package was updated recently to confirm whether this might be the case:

```
grep "upgrade " /var/log/dpkg.log
```

However in your case, the Radeon firmware might have an issue as well.